# Adverbs in comparative degree and anyone or everybody rules

Tags: comparatives

1 question. 
Can you please help to understand the use of adverb in this sentence structure and which one is correct!?
Open the brackets:
1. `A turtle moves....  (slow)  than a rabbit.`
Which one is correct "more slowly" or "slower "?

2 question.
Why do we use *anybody* instead of everyone in this sentence? As I know anyone/anybody generally are used in negative  sentences and questions.

> Anybody can do this. It's  so easy!

Thanks for you reply)

Comment: May I suggest that you make two posts, one with each question?  You have two distinct questions here.

Comment: If you are learning English, then our sister site [English Language Learners](https://ell.stackexchange.com/) is probably more suited to your needs.

Comment: What does a dictionary say about **anybody** v. **everybody**?  If that doesn't anser your Q., then go to [English Language Learners](https://ell.stackexchange.com/).

Answer (score -1, accepted):

1 question. Can you please help to understand the use of adverb in this sentence structure and which one is correct!? Open the brackets: 1. A turtle moves....  (slow)  than a rabbit. Which one is correct "more slowly" or "slower "?

A:  A rabbit that is not moving, does not move faster than a turtle that is moving.  I'm a fan of "ly" when adverbs are used, but have read that it is not in current usage.  In your example, either "more slowly" or "slower" are good choices.

2 question. Why do we use anybody instead of everyone in this sentence? As I know anyone/anybody generally are used in negative sentences and questions. 
Anybody can do this. It's so easy!

A:  It is not true that "anybody" can do, (whatever is being suggested), no matter how "easy" an author claims it to be.  But, in my experience, anyone/anybody are not generally used in negative sentences and questions.

The difference between "anybody" and "anyone" - I would avoid both.  Increasingly, there is a false globalization of assumptions, as when media hosts state, "We all use apps."  No. "we"  do not.  I would also avoid exclamation marks.

Make the instructions complete and straightforward.  "Easy" is a word that might be associated with the subject, if, in fact, you believe that most fully-abled people would find it so.